# Adding a web image to a gridview from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a Web Image that I want to add to an ASP GridView. This is what I'm doing:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.ImageUrl = @"/_layouts/15/images/Project/x-mark-3-xxl.png";
row[course.CourseName] = image;
```

I get back the name of the object in the column. I'm doing a datatable and then binding it to the gridview, so the 'row' variable you see is obviously a row of the datatable. I need to show the image in the gridview. I did this a long time ago and I can't remember how I did it. And yes, it has to be by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put an `image` back into a `row` like that. You need the `OnRowDataBound` event and add the Image to a Cell directly.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        Image image = new Image();
        image.ImageUrl = @"/_layouts/15/images/Project/" + row["imageNameColumn"].ToString();

        //add the image to the gridview
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to add the image at a later time, specify the Row and Cell by their index.

```
GridView1.Rows[4].Cells[2].Controls.Add(image);
```

Update

You can do this. Loop the cells and check if it is an Odd or Even cell and add the image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.ImageUrl = @"/image.jpg";
        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but I have one more request. This is somewhat what my grid looks like:

user   |  X  |  X |
user2 |  X  |     |
user3 |      |  X |

I need the X to be replaced by the images.

Sorry I can't get the formatting correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! You have helped me a lot!